# How browsers know what cookies to send to server when requesting?

Tags: php, javascript, security, cookies, csrf

I know how the cookies work, just started to dig why Codeigniter does not store  generated csrf token in SESSION, it just store in cookie. Concerned about security,  I'v started to think about php setcookie() function params such as path and domain. And I have asked myself is it possible to set 'evil_cookie' with a path='/' and domain = 'www.goodsite.com' from another domain, from some 'www.evilsite.com'? And another question is, will 'evil_cookie' be sent to 'www.goodsite.com' when performing request to 'www.goodsite.com'?

So, I did a test. I'v created 'set_cookie.php' file and uploaded it to some 'www.evilsite.com':

```
setcookie('evil_cookie', 'gotcha', time() + 60 * 30, '/', 'www.goodsite.com');
```

I was using Firefox and Firebug + Cookie plugins for viewing sent and received cookies. So, I did receive 'evil_cookie' after the request to 'www.evilsite.com/set_cookie.php'. However, the cookie was not saved (at least there was no such cookie when viewing in firebug cookie plugin panel). Nor it was sent when requesting again to "www.evilsite.com/set_cookie.php". Just received but not saved.

From the Firefox browser point of view, it's logical and secure to save cookie for current domain only. IMHO those set cookie() params such as path and domain are primarily for managing cookies for current domain and its subdomains but not for external domains. I was a little bit upset I was unable to find related info on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), so I'm not sure is it a browser related behavior and specifics how it deals with "3rd party cookies" or it's more a standard? Does all browsers behave the same? If there's any solid and reliable source for such statements please share.

That is also relevant to another use of cookies - store session data (without using PHP native sessions, for example Codeigniter does so). So, if all browsers do not allow to safe cookie with other than current domain then It's OK.  However, it does not protect from CSRF as 'www.evilsite.com' might contain evil javascript code that will create 'evil_cookie' directly on the client when a user will perform and get a request from 'www.evilsite.com'.

Comment: `$domain` in the documentation means relative path like `/forum/`, not an entire url.

Comment: I do not agree. For that stuff is 'path' parameter. Domain is a full domain or subdomain. Check out php.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> […] is it possible to set 'evil_cookie' with a path='/' and domain = 'www.goodsite.com' from another domain, from some 'www.evilsite.com'?

No, user agents should ignore *Set-Cookie* directives with *Domain* attributes that do not [domain-match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3) the current requested domain:

> The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute
> specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin
> server.  For example, the user agent will accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "example.com" or of "foo.example.com" from
> foo.example.com, but the user agent will not accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "bar.example.com" or of "baz.foo.example.com".

Such cookies would not even be accepted by user agents. Similar applies to the *Path* and *Secure* attributes.

See also [*How do browser cookie domains work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/53114) for examples of how the *Domain* attribute values are interpreted by user agents.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): a site can only write and read cookies for its own domain.

Comment: So, domain parameter in setcookie() is only for managing cookie availability to current domain and its subdomains?

Comment: -1 You’re wrong. You can set a cookie in `example.com` that is available in `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies can only be set for the current domain or its subdomains as you have alredy found out (otherwise, anyone could replace anyone else's cookie; chaos would ensue). This is enforced by the browser: if you attempt to set cookies for another domain from the server side (using an HTTP header) the browser will ignore the cookie. If you attempt to do the same from the client side (using Javascript), the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent you from doing so.

Therefore, www.evilsite.com can set a cookie for its own domain with Javascript, but that's not an issue: it could already do that using an HTTP header. There's no new attack vector here.

Comment: I'm on accounts.google.com/signin. In Chrome dev tools/Application, under cookies, two domains are listed: https://accounts.google.com and https://accounts.youtube.com. Two completely different domains. Under each domain, all cookies follow same origin policy. But APISID, SAPISIX, and SID cookie exists under both with the same value. Are these cookies shared between domains? Why does Goolgle.com have YouTube's cookies listed in chrome dev tools?