# Cookies being set twice

Tags: php, cookies

Why are cookies being set twice for my website? One set of cookies is stored for "www.example.com" and the same set is being stored for "example.com".

Comment: Cookies are bound to domains. If you browse both, then you'll get cookies for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, you are allowing access to your site via both domain names `example.com` and `www.example.com` and you have not specified the domain name for which your cookie should be set.  The [fifth parameter to `setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) specifies domain, so set it to `example.com` only. That will make it available to the higher domain `www.example.com` as well.

```
setcookie('key', 'value', time(), '/path', 'example.com');
```

Via URL rewriting, you can force all users of your site to one or the other of those domains before the cookie is set, but that is merely a solution for consistency of user experience, not a way to manage cookies.

From the docs:

> #### domain
>
> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Comment: If I set that fifth parameter to example.com, would it create a problem for people trying to access cookies through the www.example.com ? Or it would work for both?

Comment: Just wanted to point out this question/answer if people are curious [how browser cookies interpret the domain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/1168661)