# Set custom CookieManager while using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, cookiemanager

I ported to Volley and I realized that it doesn't manage cookies. I then looked for an answer on how to do so, and the best so far is it of setting the default `CookieHandler` in the static method `setDefault()` of the class `CookieHandler`.

I created then a new `CookieManager` as suggested in many questions with my custom `CookieStore`, but when I tried queuing a request I get this stacktrace:

```
07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414): [22379] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414): java.lang.NullPointerException

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at java.net.CookieManager.get(CookieManager.java:112)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.prepareRawRequestHeaders(HttpEngine.java:540)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:184)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)

07-26 00:27:04.509: E/Volley(11414):    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
```

I'm using a Moto G with Android 4.4.2 to debug, and I set the `CookieManager` in the `Application` object (in the `onCreate()`).

I guess I'm not missing anything. I'd really appreciate some ideas to solve this problem, or some workaround.

It may be related to that bug of Android Kitkat not working correctly when the default `CookieManager` is changed ([Android 4.4 KitKat not receiving cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622777/android-4-4-kitkat-not-receiving-cookies))

Comment: You should post the code from where the error is coming from.

Comment: It happens whenever the method `add` of the Volley Queue is invoked.