# Pass session value in Volley in android

Tags: android, cookies, android-volley, httpcookie

I am required to pass cookie value in my next service after log in I am using volley library to call services. I have successfully saved cookie using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743595/942224)  it successfully saves ids in preference.

i have use getHeader for next request

```
@Override

public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

    return myApp.getSessionCookie();
}
```

but for my next request how to use this value?