# Android clear ram memory resets apps

Tags: php, android, ram, android-volley

I have an android application that uses android volley for some php files.
I see that other apps on the market restore themselves when I hit clear ram memory. My application loses the volley httpclient and I lose my session for php.
What happens to the app when "Clear memory" is called and whan can I do to refresh my app the right way?

I see that the app closes, but when I reopen it from "recent apps panel" it opens on the last activity, but my first activity does the login and creates the session.

I found about session coockies here : [Using cookies with Android volley library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library)
But I'm wondering what does "clear ram" does.

Comment: Who knows what they do?  But you should not be using them anyway.  Not needed on Android and bad for performance.

Comment: Take for example, open Facebook app, clear ram then enter again from recent apps, it will load for a second and it will work again.
I think it restarts activities.

Comment: My point was, just don't use "memory cleaners".  if someone uses them, it's their problem.  They should not be used on Android.

Comment: I'm talking about the android memory cleaner, the built-in one. People use it often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base activity from which all your activities inherit. In the base activity's `onResume` , check for valid session (including valid cookies) , if not valid, reopen the login activity, which will recreate new session/cookie credentials, and update session object.

login and session management needs to apart from your base or regular activity.

Comment: But instead of reopening login activity I will store the sessionId in preferences and put it in my requsets as a cookie.