# Authentification from Android Device against Spring Security Rest API

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

i have an SPRING Backend with an REST-API. It is secured by username and password. When i open it with my pc browser at first the login screen is shown and after i added the credentials i can access the api fluendly.

When i try the same through an Android APP, i get every time referred to the login screen. To auth on the Android Side i use an REST API Request which is by default accessable.
Is the internally Android App Browser not compatible to store session cookies? Everytime a new   HTTP session gets created. Im using Volley for the requests

spring-security.xml

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/user/login" access="permitAll" /> <!--IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_GROUP_LEADER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_GROUP_LEADER')" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/admin" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"    
    />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>


<authentication-manager alias="authManager">
   <authentication-provider >

        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select username,password, enabled from user where username=?"
      authorities-by-username-query=
        "select username, name as role from role r,user u where u.role_id = r.id and username =? " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

the code in the controller from the rest api

```
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsSvc.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "123",userDetails.getAuthorities());

    Authentication authentication = authManager.authenticate(token);

    log.debug("Logging in with [{}]", authentication.getPrincipal());
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
```

Spring Security DEBUG

```
************************************************************

Request received for POST '/api/user/create':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@36dc8ced

servletPath:/api/user/create
pathInfo:null
headers: 
if-modified-since: Sat, 03 Jan 2015 12:35:50 GMT+00:00
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
user-agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; GT-P7100 Build/IMM76D)
host: 192.168.178.36:8088
connection: Keep-Alive
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 124


Security filter chain: [
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2015-01-03 13:53:46 INFO  Spring Security Debugger:39 - 

************************************************************

New HTTP session created: A430DD754F7F6E466D07B10D1DDCCEF7

Call stack: 

    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.Logger.info(Logger.java:29)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:238)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:40)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:184)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


************************************************************


2015-01-03 13:53:46 INFO  Spring Security Debugger:39 - 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/login':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@36dc8ced

servletPath:/login
pathInfo:null
headers: 
if-modified-since: Sat, 03 Jan 2015 12:35:50 GMT+00:00
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
user-agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; GT-P7100 Build/IMM76D)
host: 192.168.178.36:8088
connection: Keep-Alive
accept-encoding: gzip


Security filter chain: [
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.
```

volley

```
    CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault( manager  );

    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the problem may be that you are implementing your own custom authentication controller endpoint and not using the full spring-security chain.

The normal filter chain will still get invoked on all requests as per your xml config, but by just calling authenticate() method in a controller will just do that, and not the rest of the authentication sucess handler stuff e.g. you won't actually be setting a cookie on the response with your adhoc controller authentication)

The easiest way to test this is just curl the url directly, or use something like postman (chrome plugin for rest apis) to test the api authentication endpoit and see if any cookeis are being set on the response.

If you have control over the serverside code (e.g. you can change it and aren't just working on the android app), here are a few thoughts:

- I would avoid custom authentication endpoints and trying to hand-roll the security stuff - spring security is really good at that stuff.
- Assuming you don't want to go with oauth and the complexity of that solutions for the API, then take a look at [Google's recommended approach for securing APIs for mobile apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps).  It's similar to approach you have taken, but for the login you just embed a web view in the android app and use it to let the user login directly on the standard spring security form (so get to take advantage of Spring-security default behaviour e.g. cookies etc), then in the app you just grab a user token from the web response and then store that - which can then be used in all API requests as a request header (so user doesnt have to keep logging in on the mobile app)

I wrote up an overview of the approach here:

[Securing your API for mobile access](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/securing-your-api-for-mobile-access.html)

and have put together a spring security implementation here as well.

[Securing your mobile API with Spring Security](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/securing-your-mobile-api-spring-security.html)

Comment: I tried the postman plugin. The login works on chrome fluendly with the code i had written. so the security chain seems to be done correctly. even when i skip the .authenticate part it seems to work on pc side. i will try your other suggestions. cookies get send back

Comment: The API login works on chrome? (e.g. logout/clear browser cookies and then make a request to the rest API passing in whatever credentials you need to that api request?) How are you passing in login credentials to the API authentication? Are you posting a form to the API with username/password?

Comment: i followed you suggestion and tried it with postmann. i logout/clear the browser cache, make the post request and got a response with cookie back. after that i can use the api and admin backend. its a post request with username and password which are sended to the api and there verified by the code above. in the example with password 123 (which gets internally encoded). 

the json looks  like 
{"username":"...","password":"..."}
and gives back a string like "successfull" and a JSESSIONID like A13B1D3300B6B7D48ACC4626966872AE as a cookie

Comment: Interesting - I would still avoid a custom made authentication method in a controller, but if that controller is still providing the cookie correctly in the browser then the problem must be in the android app. Have you looked at this question about the HttpStack - is that all set up correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library/21271347#21271347

Answer (score 0):

Tried your suggestion and got it working.

After i had checked, that the backend transport the needed cookie, i adjust volley so that it stores the transmitted cookie and retransmit it on every request after that as a token. The cookie get stored in the preferences.

```
public GsonRequest(...)
  .....

if(PreferencesManager.getInstance().getSessionCookie()!=null)
       this.headers.put("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+ PreferencesManager.getInstance().getSessionCookie());

@Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String cookie = MyApp.get().checkSessionCookie(response.headers);
            PreferencesManager.getInstance().setSessionCookie(cookie);
               .....
    }
```

as stated by vmirinov on [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library) with slidly modification

```
public final String checkSessionCookie(Map<String, String> headers) {
        if (headers.containsKey(SET_COOKIE_KEY)
                && headers.get(SET_COOKIE_KEY).toLowerCase().contains(SESSION_COOKIE)) {
            String cookie = headers.get(SET_COOKIE_KEY);
            if (cookie.length() > 0) {
                String[] splitCookie = cookie.split(";");
                String[] splitSessionId = splitCookie[0].split("=");
                cookie = splitSessionId[1];
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = _preferences.edit();
                prefEditor.putString(SESSION_COOKIE, cookie);
                prefEditor.commit();
                return cookie;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```