# Use HttpUrlConnection with volley

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-volley

I read everywhere that volley will use either HttpUrlConnection for newer versions api or HttpClient for older version and I'm trying to tell volley to only use the HttpUrlConnection.

My main goal is to setup volley to execute requests using a cookie I have in store, and to do that I know I need to set the HttpUrlConnection with the cookie and then pass it to volley to use as the default implementation.

So far so good but I have no idea how to start HttpUrlConnection and add the cookie to it.

Can someone please give me a small example of how to initialise HttpUrlConnection and add a cookie to it and then pass it on to volley?

I was able to perform such a request on HttpUrlConnection itself and it worked but how do I set it up to use with volley?

```
URL urlLink = new URL(url2);
HttpURLConnection conenction = (HttpURLConnection)urlLink.openConnection();
conenction.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```

Comment: I recommend that you use the [OkHttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp). It has lots of optimizations, and `HttpUrlConnection` has some bugs pre-Gingerbread, which is why the default `HttpStack` implementation in Volley uses Apache's `HttpClient` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I read everywhere that volley will use either HttpUrlConnection for newer versions api or HttpClient for older version and I'm trying to tell volley to only use the HttpUrlConnection.

This is correct. See lines 54-60 of the [`Volley` source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1a39583f0ee06329f7918ed9a4c7d0e7cd342917/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/Volley.java). If your app is running on a device using Gingerbread (API level 9) or higher, it is already using `HttpUrlConnection` for all requests.

If you really want to use your own `HttpUrlConnection` instance for your requests, you will need to implement your own `HttpStack` (see Volley's [`HurlStack`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1a39583f0ee06329f7918ed9a4c7d0e7cd342917/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/HurlStack.java) for an example). You can use `Volley# newRequestQueue(Context, HttpStack)` to tell Volley to use your custom stack.

There are a number of alternatives for sending cookies however. I recommend checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library) for some of those alternatives.