# Volley Response headers ignores set-cookie

Tags: android, android-volley

I have an android app and i am making a request using Volley. In the header of the response it is sending back a set cookie header that i need to save. The issue is i override parse network response and in the response headers map all the headers are there except the set cookie header. I know its being sent because i have Charles http monitor so i know its being sent but volley is ignoring it. any suggestions?

in my class that extends request and the set-cookie is always empty

```
 @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        T parsedResponse = null;
        switch (type){

                parsedResponse = (T)Parser.parse(new String(response.data));
                String sessionId = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie");
                if(sessionId!=null)
                {
                    sessionId = sessionId.split("=")[1];
                    SessionHelper.saveSessionId(mContext, sessionId);
                    Log.e("session","saved session");
                }
        }

        return Response.success(parsedResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

    }
```

[image: and here is the request going into the device, with the set cookie header]

Comment: I think you can find a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library)