# Volley custom headers not working even when set

Tags: android, android-volley

I have setup Volley in my app but I am stuck at trying to send request headers (cookies) in each request. I have created a custom request and have overriden getHeaders like below:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

    String sessionRequest = "source=Android-" + AppUtils.getDeviceUUID(visnetawrap);
    if (visnetawrap.visnetaUser != null) {
        if (visnetawrap.visnetaUser.getUserIdString() != null) {
            //headers.put("UserSession", "id=" + visnetawrap.visnetaUser.getUserIdString());
            sessionRequest += ",id=" + visnetawrap.visnetaUser.getUserIdString();
        }
        if (visnetawrap.visnetaUser.userToken != null) {
            //headers.put("UserSession", "token=" + visnetawrap.visnetaUser.userToken);
            sessionRequest += ",token=" + visnetawrap.visnetaUser.userToken;
        }
    }
    //headers.put("UserSession", "source=Android-" + AppUtils.getDeviceUUID(visnetawrap));

    headers.put("UserSession", sessionRequest);

    Log.d("RequestHeaders", headers.toString());

    return headers;
}
```

However, when I create the request I get an error back from the server saying they are not set. It is not a server side issue because it used to work with retrofit. Any suggestions on why this might be?

Comment: Have you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library)?

Comment: I have and I tried it, didn't work for me unless I am doing it wrong...which answer is best? I tried the top one. I am using OkHttpClient, maybe that is the issue? Also all of those values are set in my function above so when it returns the headers it should be sending them?

Comment: Post the response message from your server pls

Comment: It was just returning unknown error but i did a print stack trace and found out it was because of a timeout.

Comment: Timeout? Check network connection or setRetryPolicy like `request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Comment: What is the value of DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS? I will try setting a retry policy. Nevermind it is 2500, let me see if this works ill get back to you...

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I add it as my answer, if it help you solve your issue, you can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have commented, for **Timeout** problem, you should check network connection or **setRetryPolicy** like the following code:

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```