# How to use session and redirect in Volley library

Tags: android, session, cookies, android-volley

I can request to my API by this python code snippet (use `requests python`):

```
session = requests.session()
r=session.post(url,data=post_data, auth=(username , passwd))
```

Server will use this session and redirect my request to another get request then return the json response successfully.

I want to implement this api request on Android using Volley library. I have figured all day, and there is no luck. I can request an GET api successfully, but POST.

I have tried all answer on [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library/21271347)

It seem I cannot create a session for Volley can use it.

Does anyone have experience in using session/cookie for Volley library?

Comment: It might be treated as an offtop, but why don't you try to do this with Picasso lib? (http://square.github.io/picasso/) Very customisable, well-known library and have a vibrant community around it. Just a thought.

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov As I know, Picasso is a library supports for download and display image. What I want now is download data from API.