# Android Hybrid App + Volley, Cookies and WebView

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-volley

I have researched for > 15 hours about this problem:
I am building a Hybrid App , I login with the Volley Framework (native View),
as soon as I login I fetch the response Header,extract the Cookie and save it into my sharedprefs. After successful login I have a native mainscreen that contains links to several Webviews, 
how do I pass the Cookie I received from the login into the Webview?
90% of the Answers on the Internet use CookieSyncManager, which is deprecated.
I tried the java.net.CookieManager also, nothing of it works.

Here's my Code

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new WebView(this);

    setContentView(mWebView);

    cookies = pref.getString(Const.COOKIE_KEY,"null");
    userID = pref.getString(Const.USER_ID_KEY,"null");
    mUrl = Const.PERFORMANCE_WEBVIEW_LINK + Const.USER_ID;
    String cookieText = Const.COOKIE_KEY + "=" + cookies;

    //Approach A Environment for the Cookies
    //Does not work
    cookieSync = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    cookieManager.setCookie(mUrl, cookieText);
    cookieSync.sync();

    SystemClock.sleep(10000);

    /*APPROACH B, sending the Cookies with header
      ##Did not Work##
    final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

    Log.d("cookie", cookieText);
    headers.put("Cookie",cookieText);
    */

    if(cookies.equals("null") || userID.equals("null")) {
        Toast.makeText(PerformanceWebview.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Logging Out
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        //mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl,headers);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        Toast.makeText(PerformanceWebview.this,cookieText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("URL", "URL: " + mUrl);
    }


}
```

I also tried passing a WebClient to the WebView and overrode it's shouldOverrideURl method and passed the headers into it.
Another approach I did was using WebSettings and passing a ChromeClient..

None of the Answers here seem to work

Comment: found a solution: called Customer to tell their backend developer to allow a way avoid Cookies and accept my client requests

Answer (score 2):

First make sure Volley uses cookies: ( see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21271347 )

```
// Make volley remember cookies

// Do this only once on app startup, and keep the reference to the cookiemanager.
// I'm saving it on an App class, but you can do something different.

App.cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(App.cookieManager);

// Note, we are using the java.net.CookieManager above.
```

Then, after for example a login call in Volley, sync the cookies to WebView:

```
// Sync cookies to webview
android.webkit.CookieManager webkitCookies = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();

for (HttpCookie cookie : App.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
    webkitCookies.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue());
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    webkitCookies.flush();
} else {
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CookieStore_ implements CookieStore{
/** this map may have null keys! */
private final Map<URI, List<HttpCookie>> map = new HashMap<URI, List<HttpCookie>>();
private android.webkit.CookieManager manager;

public CookieStore_() {
    manager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
}

public synchronized void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
    if (cookie == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("cookie == null");
    }

    uri = cookiesUri(uri);
    //add cookie to the CookieManager,be sure you have called
    //CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context) if your android version           
    //is lower than Lollipop
    manager.setCookie(uri.toString(),cookie.toString());

    List<HttpCookie> cookies = map.get(uri);
    if (cookies == null) {
        cookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
        map.put(uri, cookies);
    } else {
        cookies.remove(cookie);
    }
    cookies.add(cookie);
}

private URI cookiesUri(URI uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return new URI("http", uri.getHost(), null, null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        return uri; // probably a URI with no host
    }
}

public synchronized List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("uri == null");
    }

    List<HttpCookie> result = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();

    // get cookies associated with given URI. If none, returns an empty list
    List<HttpCookie> cookiesForUri = map.get(uri);
    if (cookiesForUri != null) {
        for (Iterator<HttpCookie> i = cookiesForUri.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            HttpCookie cookie = i.next();
            if (cookie.hasExpired()) {
                i.remove(); // remove expired cookies
            } else {
                result.add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }

    // get all cookies that domain matches the URI
    for (Map.Entry<URI, List<HttpCookie>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (uri.equals(entry.getKey())) {
            continue; // skip the given URI; we've already handled it
        }

        List<HttpCookie> entryCookies = entry.getValue();
        for (Iterator<HttpCookie> i = entryCookies.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            HttpCookie cookie = i.next();
            if (!HttpCookie.domainMatches(cookie.getDomain(), uri.getHost())) {
                continue;
            }
            if (cookie.hasExpired()) {
                i.remove(); // remove expired cookies
            } else if (!result.contains(cookie)) {
                result.add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
}

public synchronized List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
    List<HttpCookie> result = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
    for (List<HttpCookie> list : map.values()) {
        for (Iterator<HttpCookie> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            HttpCookie cookie = i.next();
            if (cookie.hasExpired()) {
                i.remove(); // remove expired cookies
            } else if (!result.contains(cookie)) {
                result.add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
}

public synchronized List<URI> getURIs() {
    List<URI> result = new ArrayList<URI>(map.keySet());
    result.remove(null); // sigh
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
}

public synchronized boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
    if (cookie == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("cookie == null");
    }

    List<HttpCookie> cookies = map.get(cookiesUri(uri));
    if (cookies != null) {
        return cookies.remove(cookie);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public synchronized boolean removeAll() {
    boolean result = !map.isEmpty();
    map.clear();
    return result;
}

public void clearCookies(){
    map.clear();
}
```

}

this class was copied from CookieStoreImpl and added a android.webkit.CookieManager in it,when add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) get called, add the cookie to the cookieManager,then when webview load a url which has a match in cookieManager,webview add matched cookies to the request's headers.

below is a helper class

```
public class CookieUtil {
private CookieManager manager;
private CookieStore_ cookieStore_;
private CookieSyncManager syncManager;
private static CookieUtil cookieUtil;
private boolean isInitialed = false;

private CookieUtil(Context context) {
    manager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    if (!Util.hasLollipop()){
        syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
    }
    cookieStore_ = new CookieStore_();
}

public void clearCookies(){
    if (manager.hasCookies()){
        if (Util.hasLollipop()){
            manager.removeAllCookies(null);
        }else {
            manager.removeAllCookie();
        }
    }
    cookieStore_.clearCookies();
}

public static CookieUtil getCookieUtil(Context context){
    if (cookieUtil == null)
        cookieUtil = new CookieUtil(context);
    return cookieUtil;
}

public void sync(){
    if (Util.hasLollipop()){
        manager.flush();
    }else {
        syncManager.sync();
    }
}

public void setThirdPartyCookieAcceptable(WebView webView){
    if (Util.hasLollipop()){
        manager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
    }
}

public void initCookieHandler(){
    if (isInitialed)
        return;
    isInitialed = true;
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new java.net.CookieManager(cookieStore_, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER));
}
```

}

if you don't need to save cookies to local storage,you can share volley cookies to webview through a single line

```
CookieUtil.getCookieUtil(context).initCookieHandler();
```

and don't forget to call clearCookies() when logout