# How to manage cookies between different activities, using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, session-cookies

Following the answers to this question ([Using cookies with Android volley library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library/25388897#25388897)), I was able to handle to cookie for a single Activity (let's call this Activity Login). Is there a way to handle the cookie for different activities (e.g. I have an activity User_Activity that needs the session-cookie to make a request to get more data on the user) ?

Thanks.

Comment: The cookie store is persisted in the application level, not the activity level according to that answer. What problems are you running into?

Comment: When I make another request, I have an error 500, which is equivalent to the lack of session. I don't have a clue about how to solve that. I did not understand neither where I was supposed to set the cookie manager.

Comment: 500 is "internal server error", nothing to do with cookies... And I'm not sure why you linked to that particular answer when there are others there.

Comment: The way the server is coded, the error 500 comes from the lack of cookie. I did not code the server, but that's what I have to work with.

Comment: Alright, can you please show the code you have for your single activity with an [edit]?