# Volley requests not working with Django Sessions

Tags: android, django, session, android-volley

I have a Django script running on the server that creates session variables for every request sent to the server. The script returns a specific value based on the previous stored session variables.

When I tested the script on the browser, the session on Django worked as per the requirement.

However, while using Volley to send the same request, the script considers every request as a new request without taking previous session variables into consideration.

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,Send_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Response(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

`RequestQueue defined globally and context assigned in the onCreate() method`

P.S I rechecked by requesting from the browser and it works. So there are no issues on the Django End. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to [configure Volley to use cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21271347/2646526)?

Comment: Did you corsfilter kind of thing in back end?? I have same problem when back end is developed using spring framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Volley does not support Cookie by default. you should override `StringRequest` class as below shown:

```
public class StringRequest extends com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest {

private final Map<String, String> _params;

/**
 * @param method
 * @param url
 * @param params
 *            A {@link HashMap} to post with the request. Null is allowed
 *            and indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
 * @param listener
 * @param errorListener
 */
public StringRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params, Listener<String> listener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, listener, errorListener);

    _params = params;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return _params;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest#parseNetworkResponse(com.android.volley.NetworkResponse)
 */
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    // since we don't know which of the two underlying network vehicles
    // will Volley use, we have to handle and store session cookies manually
    MyApp.get().checkSessionCookie(response.headers);

    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.android.volley.Request#getHeaders()
 */
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

    if (headers == null
            || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    MyApp.get().addSessionCookie(headers);

    return headers;
}
}
```

and your application class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static final String SET_COOKIE_KEY = "Set-Cookie";
    private static final String COOKIE_KEY = "Cookie";
    private static final String SESSION_COOKIE = "sessionid";

    private static MyApp _instance;
  private RequestQueue _requestQueue;
  private SharedPreferences _preferences;

    public static MyApp get() {
        return _instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        _instance = this;
            _preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        _requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return _requestQueue;
    }


    /**
     * Checks the response headers for session cookie and saves it
     * if it finds it.
     * @param headers Response Headers.
     */
    public final void checkSessionCookie(Map<String, String> headers) {
        if (headers.containsKey(SET_COOKIE_KEY)
                && headers.get(SET_COOKIE_KEY).startsWith(SESSION_COOKIE)) {
                String cookie = headers.get(SET_COOKIE_KEY);
                if (cookie.length() > 0) {
                    String[] splitCookie = cookie.split(";");
                    String[] splitSessionId = splitCookie[0].split("=");
                    cookie = splitSessionId[1];
                    Editor prefEditor = _preferences.edit();
                    prefEditor.putString(SESSION_COOKIE, cookie);
                    prefEditor.commit();
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Adds session cookie to headers if exists.
     * @param headers
     */
    public final void addSessionCookie(Map<String, String> headers) {
        String sessionId = _preferences.getString(SESSION_COOKIE, "");
        if (sessionId.length() > 0) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(SESSION_COOKIE);
            builder.append("=");
            builder.append(sessionId);
            if (headers.containsKey(COOKIE_KEY)) {
                builder.append("; ");
                builder.append(headers.get(COOKIE_KEY));
            }
            headers.put(COOKIE_KEY, builder.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

also You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743595/2999385) for more ...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using volley library in other scripting language, You need to go through about volley library  [here](http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put) ..

Additionally volley store the cache values by default,so your code did not work second time  (*that means return the same values*)

so you can try [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) default method to use this type of server actions.

Thanks hope its help!!!