# Session variables not working in php while sending request from volley in android device

Tags: php, android, session, android-volley

I am using session variables to pass data from script to another.
When I am using Postman to send POST request then after redirecting it to another script through header, all variables are accessible.
But when I try to send request through android device using Volley library,then printing these variables shows them as empty.

I am not much aware of Volley or Session concepts, so I might be doing something wrong here.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library). And setup cookie manager. Volley doesn't manage cookies default.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.