# Android Kotlin - Volley Unexpected response code 500

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, kotlin, android-volley

I made REST API with Django Rest Framework. Currently, I'm working on a mobile app for my site. When I do POST request (it's my second POST request in my app) I'm getting this error:

> E/Volley: [385] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://laude.ct8.pl/api/user/data/aktualizacja/

Here is my code:

```
private val UPDATE_URL = "http://laude.ct8.pl/api/user/data/aktualizacja/"
private var volleyRequest: RequestQueue? = null
private val jsonObj = JSONObject()

volleyRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

private fun aktualizacja() {

        jsonObj.put("librus_user", usernameEdit.text)
        jsonObj.put("librus_pswd", passwordEdit.text)

        val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPDATE_URL, jsonObj,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    val user = Intent(this, UserActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(user)
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                })
        req.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)

        volleyRequest!!.add(req)
    }
```

When I use same data on my website I'm not getting any errors, I got it only on a mobile app. 
Thanks for help !

Comment: 500 means there's an internal server error. This isn't an Android issue, this is a server/website issue

Comment: Error 500 is the Server error that means there is no problem with your code (there may be an error) but you have to check your server error cause before checking your app code! Show logs in your server!

Comment: @Xenolion I have only access to error and access logs. I'm not getting any of that.

Comment: After a careful observation of the site above I have figured what might be the cause of the error above! Have you already solved it or should I still answer it!

Answer (score 0):

The server error is caused by you making `JsonObjectRequest` and passing an `JsonObject` as a body of parameter while your server requires them as `Strings`(*I observed the link!*). The quick fix is to use `StringRequest` and pass your parameters as a String as ! Check the code below to get the idea!

```
private val UPDATE_URL = "http://laude.ct8.pl/api/user/data/aktualizacja/"
private var volleyRequest: RequestQueue? = null

volleyRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

private fun aktualizacja() {

        val req = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                UPDATE_URL,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val user = Intent(this, UserActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(user)

                }, Response.ErrorListener { e ->

               Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }) {
            public override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("username", usernameEdit.text)
                params.put("password", passwordEdit.text)
                return params
            }
        }
        req.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)

    volleyRequest!!.add(req)

}
```

You should also NOTE that the response is also a `String` so if you need it as a `JSONOject` convert it.

*Sorry if you may get any errors in the code! I wrote the code in Java and convert to Kotlin using Android Studio!! I hope you will get the general idea!*

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Okay but I have realised that even visiting the link using the browser it crashes leading to an exception so you have 500 code which is the server error. Please post using the browser first trying to debug and all will go well!

Comment: This is the error `During handling of the above exception (list assignment index out of range), another exception occurred:`

Comment: Yeah, this error shows up when you put incorrect data. I shouldn't get this error because I use correct data.

Comment: Can you share with me the correct data or is it classified?

Comment: Sorry but I can't. This is data for my school.

Comment: Okay then make some fake data (username and password) and allow me to debug for you!

Comment: Done. First, you need to login to this url: `http://laude.ct8.pl/api/user/login/` with this data: username: `fakeUser` and password: `fakeUser`. Then you can go to this url: `http://laude.ct8.pl/api/user/data/aktualizacja/` and use this data: username: `fake` password: `fakePassword`

Comment: Can I answer the question using java?

Comment: Yeah, no problem.

Comment: Is the names `librus_user` and `librus_pswd` for password?? Thats what I see from the form! But we used `username` and `password` for it!

Comment: Yeah, I changed it yesterday. I will edit my code in my question.

Comment: I have finished the request the site needs a person to be logged in first before making the second request! So I am getting `AuthFailerError` I can not make both requests!

Comment: Yeah, I was getting the same error. Is it way to avoid it?

Comment: Oooh your question becomes good now and you need to find a way to store a session using a cookie or something. I will show you the way here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library

Comment: I added this code `CookieHandler.setDefault(CookieManager())` into my login actvity and I'm still getting same error.