# How to set and check cookies wih JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, cookies, jax-rs

I am a noobie with RESTful API and I am trying to build a Login service in which I provide an email and password and if the validation is successful - to store a cookie.
In addition, how do I check the cookie(if stored)?

How can this be achieved?

```
@Path("/login")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response Login(final String i_LoginDetails) throws JSONException {
    final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(i_LoginDetails);
    try {
        if (isValidUser(obj.getString("email"), obj.getString("password"))) {
            // Set a cookie
        } else {
            // return error invalid-credentials message
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.ok("TEST").build();
}
```

And how do I check the cookie(if set)?

Answer (score 54):

You can do the following:

- To store a new cookie:

  ```
  @GET
  @Path("/login")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response login() {
      NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("name", "123");
      return Response.ok("OK").cookie(cookie).build();
  }
  ```
- To retrieve the cookie (`javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie`):

  ```
  @GET
  @Path("/foo")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response foo(@CookieParam("name") Cookie cookie) {
      if (cookie == null) {
          return Response.serverError().entity("ERROR").build();
      } else {
          return Response.ok(cookie.getValue()).build();
      }
  }
  ```

  However, you may only want the value:

  ```
  @GET
  @Path("/foo")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response foo(@CookieParam("name") String value) {
      System.out.println(value);
      if (value == null) {
          return Response.serverError().entity("ERROR").build();
      } else {
          return Response.ok(value).build();
      }
  }
  ```

---

By the way, you may want to try the following code:

```
@GET
@Path("/logout")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response logout(@CookieParam("name") Cookie cookie) {
    if (cookie != null) {
        NewCookie newCookie = new NewCookie(cookie, null, 0, false);
        return Response.ok("OK").cookie(newCookie).build();
    }
    return Response.ok("OK - No session").build();
}
```

This removes the cookie in the browser. The behavior depends on the implementation of JAX-RS. With RESTEasy (JBoss AS 7.0)   and  Google Chrome works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
So before every service I execute, I should use:

    if (cookie == null) {
        return Response.serverError().entity("ERROR").build();
    } else {
//Execute service
    }

How do I send the cookieparam from the client?

Comment: Depends on the client software. What client are you using? e.g. JQuery, `HttpURLConnection`, etc.

Comment: Currently I am testing both.

Comment: If you are using `jQuery.ajax`, automatically sends the cookies (in the same domain). And with `HttpURLConnection`, you just need a cookie handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15546450/870248

Comment: would there be any difference in the approach in the first example (login) if the method was annotated with `@POST` as I think it perhaps should have been?

Comment: Sorry, but "/logout" does not remove the cookie in the GlassFish 4.1 and last Google Chrome and Firefox.