# How to access set-cookie from response using javascript

Tags: javascript, setcookie

I sent a cookie from server side

```
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok( (Object) file );
response.header( "Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=test");
```

I can already view it under the '**Response Header**' of the f12 developer tools console. However, document.cookie returns an empty string. The `HttpOnly` attribute is also unchecked. I'm also not in incognito mode and have cookies enabled. I've already tried changing the **localhost** address in case it was a web server problem. Is there a way to check the cookie with java script? I just need to check if it has been passed.

Comment: can you clear all cookis and then  after response come check cookis from all domain and see if it is storing somewhere or not.

Comment: Not sure if setting the Set-Cookie header is the right way to send cookies to client. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004298/how-to-set-and-check-cookies-wih-jax-rs

Comment: @Rajesh I cleared the cookies and after calling the service, I can see the Set-Cookie values under Response Header. does that count?

Comment: @bismarck can you share the response header from server?

Comment: @Andrés I'm limited to using ResponseBuilder instead of Response that's why...

Comment: @Rajesh here is a ss https://s32.postimg.org/rexe3tzol/image.jpg

Comment: @bismarck Not sure. But you would probably need to specify the "path" & "domain" parameter. For example / as path and "" as domain. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain

Comment: @bismarck can set more parameter in set-cookies filed and try, see more cookies field https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html and also check cookies of all web domain in browser.

Comment: @Andres I can access the cookie now! It's working in chrome. In addition to adding path and domain, changing the host name from localhost into a valid web server address made it work in IE.

Thank you so much to both of you, Andres and Rajesh!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed by adding "path" & "domain" parameter.

credits to Andres
@bismarck Not sure. But you would probably need to specify the "path" & "domain" parameter. For example / as path and "" as domain. Please check this stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/… – Andrés