# How to read a cookie in JAX-RS (Jersey)

Tags: java, rest, cookies, jax-rs

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004298/how-to-set-and-check-cookies-wih-jax-rs) to read and create cookies but I can only read cookie that I create from the same subdomain.

For example if I create a cookie in `http://localhost:8080/x/y/test/create` I **can** read it from: `http://localhost:8080/x/y/test/read` but I **cannot** read it from `http://localhost:8080/x/y/test2/read` (Note the difference between **test** and **test2**)

Where is the problem? How could I read the cookie everywhere in my domain?

Here is the code:

CLASS 1

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Path("/create")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response login() {
        NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("name", "123");
        return Response.ok("OK").cookie(cookie).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/read")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response foo(@CookieParam("name") String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
        if (value == null) {
            return Response.serverError().entity("ERROR").build();
        } else {
            return Response.ok(value).build();
        }
    }

}
```

CLASS 2

```
@Path("test2")
public class Test2 {

    @GET
    @Path("/read")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response foo(@CookieParam("name") String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
        if (value == null) {
            return Response.serverError().entity("ERROR").build();
        } else {
            return Response.ok(value).build();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem was at creation time. Now I create the cookie in this way:

```
NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("name", "123", "/", "", "comment", 100, false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a default behavior. 
To set cookie to your domain, use another constructor for cookie, and set empty domain and root path:

```
domain = ""
path = "/"
```