How to create and read a cookie in Quarkus?
What I found is creating and reading cookie with Spring by using HttpServletResponse. But in my project there is a Quarkus part treating as webservice hosting :
...
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
...
@Path("/settings")
@ApplicationScoped
public class SettingResource {
    ...

    @Path("/get-date-logiciel-incremented-one-day")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDateLogicielIncrementedOneDay() {
        TMmcParametrage setting = service.getSettingByKey("DATE_LOGICIELLE");
        LocalDate dateLogicielle = LocalDate.parse(setting.getValeur());
        LocalDate futureDateLogicielle = dateLogicielle.plusDays(1);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateLogicielFuturStr = futureDateLogicielle.format(formatter);
        HashMap<String,String> ret = new HashMap<String,String>();
        ret.put("data", dateLogicielFuturStr);
        return Response.ok(ret, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
    
}

How can I create a cookie in the getDateLogicielIncrementedOneDay method ? And how to read that cookie inside another method inside the Quarkus project ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28004533/2504224 should exactly answer the question
