# `$cookies.put()` takes 30 seconds to save the cookie on disk on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, cookies

**Context:**

- We have a cordova application loading an online website. (We basically use cordova for the plugins)
- We store a cookie using `$cookies.put()`
- It works fine in desktop browsers and on iOS (as long we use expiration on the
  cookie)

**Problem:**

On Android if the user kill the application with 30 seconds after `$cookies.put()` is called the cookie will be gone on the next reboot.

If the user wait more than 30 seconds (like 35 seconds or more) everything works fine.

**Question:**

How can we force the cookie to be saved instantly (or at least much faster)?

**Notes:**

- Adding options on the cookie does not change anything
- I tried to replace the system browser with crosswalk using [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) but it does the same thing

Comment: Have you tried the local storage instead? The default security options in Safari may cause problem with cookies for some users.

Comment: The issue is on Android only.

Comment: But why are you using cookies specifically?

Comment: And my point was that some other issues could arise from using cookies.

Comment: Local storage would indeed work, but after reading a bit, there seem to be a debate wether JWTs on localstorage vs cookies security. Interesting readings: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage 
`Stormpath recommends that you store your JWT in cookies for web applications, because of the additional security they provide`, https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/ but this would be a different question I suppose. We decided to go with Cookies for simplicity. cookies will be written by django, not javascript (so using `HttpOnly` flag).

Comment: @GabLeRoux The [article](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) is aimed at JWT that have sensible information in its body. So they are trying to hide it from XSS hacks, which they haven't really achieved, it's just more complicated.

Comment: I suppose going with JWT in localstorage could be an option, but I still find the original problem weird. We should reproduce this in a minimal scenario.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and made a small plugin (still work in progress) to fix that.

It exposes the flush method, which will apply your cookie modifications (put and remove) to persistent memory.

[link to cordova-plugin-cookie-manager](https://github.com/LeBodro/cordova-plugin-cookie-manager)

Feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

The [CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) design in the android makes it difficult to implement.
The `webview` and the `cookiemanager` which contain their own `in_memory` databases and are in sync to one another hence there is no need to sync the two of them.

The `removeSessionCookie` doesn't provide a callback or any way for it to complete and since this method has been implemented in the `WebView` classic versions.

Here are some solutions in which you can sync up between `HttpUrlCookieManager` and the `android webkit cookie manager`

[Sync up link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057624/two-way-sync-for-cookies-between-httpurlconnection-java-net-cookiemanager-and)

Another thing to note here is when you use `$cookie.put()` it defines the `cookies` to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers to the client but if you use the `third party api's` to get the `cookies` it may not contain cookies only from the `client` anymore which may result in unwanted side effects.

You may refer to the link here as suggested by Author to this post -
[author' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)  and here is the link for the protocols to be used while defining the cookies [link here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

Here is another link that i stumbled upon which may help a bit

[link here](http://code.walletapp.net/post/46414301269/passing-cookie-to-webview)

or to use the same repository/database of the `webview` and the `HttpUrlConnection` you can create your own handler as implemented in the following stack thread [Stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860087/should-httpurlconnection-with-cookiemanager-automatically-handle-session-cookies)

Hope it may help you a bit.

Comment: My best guess is to implement a plugin that calls `CookieManager.flush()` since `sync()` is deprecated.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#flush()