# Asterisk Manager Interface from Android Device

Tags: android, http, asterisk, httpurlconnection

I have set up the Asterisk Server properly for allowing GUI interface, to check this I have tried & tested an already available Application for Android & tested the same with my browser.
I am able to login & view the files.
eg.
   http://192.168.8.x:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=getconfig&filename=users.conf

this commands shows me the user.conf file.

However the same commands does not works from my Android Application. It results in

Response: Error
Message: Permission denied

my code:
          1st button click:
                  try{
            new mygoogleSearch().execute(http://192.168.8.x:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=tismo&secret=tismo123);
            } 
                  catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Exception google search","Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        }

this returns:
03-27 17:27:09.468: E/GoogleSearch(21686): Response: SuccessMessage: Authentication accepted

On 2nd Button click:

```
try{
            new Execute().execute("http://192.168.8.4:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=getconfig&filename=test.conf");
} catch(Exception e) {
Log.v("Exception google search","Exception:"+e.getMessage());
}
```

class mygoogleSearch extends AsyncTask {

```
protected String doInBackground(String... searchKey) {
    ;
    String cmd = searchKey[0];
    try {
        return  action(cmd);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.v("Exception ",
                "Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```

private String action(String uRL)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String newFeed= uRL;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

```
    URL url = new URL(newFeed);
    HttpURLConnection httpconn  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpconn.setUseCaches(false);
    //httpconn.setRequestProperty("Cache", "false");
    if(httpconn.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),
                8192);
        String strLine = null;
        while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(strLine);
        }
        input.close();
    }
    return response.toString();

}
```

this returns:

03-27 17:28:31.808: E/GoogleSearch(21800): Response: ErrorMessage: Permission denied

Comment: do you login before action: getconfig ? What is in your   `/etc/asterisk/manager.conf` ?

Comment: Yes I am logging in, after that I am issuing command to getconfig.   I can easily login & view the configuration by using :    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.8.4:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin123");                  butexcept for login nothing seems to be working while using HTTP APIs
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.8.4:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=getconfig&filename=sip.conf");

Comment: new Execute().execute("http://192.168.8.4:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=tismo&secret=tismo123");

this returns:
03-27 17:27:09.468: E/GoogleSearch(21686): Response: SuccessMessage: Authentication accepted

then on next button click:
    
  new Execute().execute(""http://192.168.8.4:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=getconfig&filename=sip.conf"");

03-27 17:28:31.808: E/GoogleSearch(21800): Response: ErrorMessage: Permission denied

Comment: do you connect to the same session? @see my example/answer

Comment: No..I guess that was my mistake..i am trying to fix it now..

Comment: finally this worked for me..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674371/how-to-use-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a CookieManager to connect to the same session.

[Quote from the asteriskbook "the definitive Guide"](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/I_sect111_tt1376.html)
"The LOGIN command authenticates credentials for the Manager interface’s HTML view. 
Once you are logged in, Asterisk stores a cookie on your browser (valid for the length of the httptimeout setting). This cookie is used to connect to the same session."

*Update:* Examples of a CookieManager Storage to mimic the Browser:
[How to use Cookies with HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674371/how-to-use-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-for-android), [persist Cookies using HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349266/how-do-i-persist-cookies-when-using-httpurlconnection)

Comment: Well I guess you are right..I need to use cookie...I tried few implementations...but still I need to figure the correct way to use cookies.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674371/how-to-use-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-for-android

Comment: finally this worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674371/how-to-use-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-for-android