# How to use Cookies in HttpURLConnection for ANDROID?

Tags: android, session-cookies, httpurlconnection, httpcookie, asteriskami

I am trying to create an Application for Asterisk Interface, the configuration setup has been done properly as I have double checked it.

It seems the reason why I can't access Config files from Asterisk server has to do with the connection. I need to use a cookie for connecting to the same instance of the login session.

But so far I am unable to use Cookie Properly need a little help.

I am supposed to login by pressing button1 (bt1) and get config file by pressing button2 (btn2).

```
public class AsteriskInterface extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = " AsteriskInterface";

    EditText ed1;
    Button bt1,bt2;
    static String url ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
    static String logincmd ="http://192.168.8.2:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin123";
    static String getfilecmd = "http://192.168.8.2:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=getconfig&filename=sip.conf";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ed1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        bt1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        bt2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.config);
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{
                    new Execute().execute(logincmd);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Exception execute", "Exception:"+e.getMessage());
                }           
            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {    
                try{
                    new Execute().execute(getfilecmd);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Exception execute", "Exception:"+e.getMessage());
                }
                //myWebView.loadUrl(cmd2);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void Response(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG,result);  
    }
}

class Execute extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    List<String> cookies = null;

    protected String doInBackground(String... searchKey) {

        String cmd = searchKey[0];
        try {
            return  action2(cmd);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.v("Exception execute do back ground", "Exception:"+e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            AsteriskInterface.Response(result);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.v("Exception excecute onPost Execute",
                    "Exception:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String action2(String uRL) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        Log.v("Execute","execute url:"+uRL);
        URL url = new URL(uRL);
        HttpURLConnection httpconn  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        DataOutputStream out;
        DataInputStream in;

        if(cookies==null){
            httpconn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
        }
        if(cookies!=null){
            for(String cookie : cookies){
                httpconn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            }
        }
        httpconn.setDoOutput(true);
        String post = "mobile_app="+URLEncoder.encode("1","UTF-8");
        out = new DataOutputStream(httpconn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(post);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in = new DataInputStream(httpconn.getInputStream());
        String line = "";
        String data = "";
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
            data+=line;
        }

        if(httpconn.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),
                    8192);
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(strLine);
            }
            input.close();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

I can make out that I am getting connected to previous login session. But now how to issue a new command?

> 03-28 10:02:15.861: V/Execute(4261): execute
>   url:http://192.168.8.x:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=login&username=admin&secret=admin123 03-28 10:02:18.871: V/Exception execute do back ground(4261):
>   Exception:Already connected 03-28 10:02:23.651: V/Execute(4261):
>   execute
>   url:http://192.168.8.x:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=getconfig&filename=sip.conf
>   03-28 10:02:26.691: V/Exception execute do back ground(4261):
>   Exception:Already connected 03-28 10:02:26.721: D/dalvikvm(4261):
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 226K, 8% free 7430K/8007K, paused 24ms+3ms, total
>   61ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private String action(String uRL)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        Log.v("Execute","execute url:"+uRL);
        URL url = new URL(uRL);
        HttpURLConnection httpconn  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if(sCookie!=null && sCookie.length()>0){
            httpconn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sCookie);
        }

        if(httpconn.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),
                    8192);
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(strLine);
            }
            input.close();
        }

        String cookie = httpconn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
        if(cookie!=null && cookie.length()>0){
            sCookie = cookie;
        }
        return response.toString();

    }
```

Comment: is sCookie is Static?