# WebEngine "keep me logged in" functionality

Tags: javafx-2

Is there any way to store state, basically to have a "keep me logged in" functionality like browsers do?
I've been looking into the CookieManager, and search a lot but haven't been able to find anything on this.
I have a social feeds reader, in which if a user clicks on a link it is opened on a WebView. The thing is, that on every run of my app, when they click on a link pointing to a private facebook post, they need to log in to their accounts in order to view it, which is quite uncomfortable.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [How do I persist cookies when using HTTPUrlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349266/how-do-i-persist-cookies-when-using-httpurlconnection)
and this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/custom.html
which allowed me to create a persistent cookie handler.