# Persistent cookie in a JavaFX Webview for Facebook login

Tags: facebook, cookies, webview, javafx, setcookie

This is probably a trivial question, but - strange enough - I was not able to find a solution on the web.

In my (almost) batch application that pulls data from the Facebook API I use a WebView in a JFX Panel to bring up the Facebook Login and Authorization Form. Then, I can get back the access token and do my job.

But even if I check to "remember me" and save the browser, the next time I launch the job, I have to authenticate again. My idea is that it's because the cookie was not saved.

How can I made the Facebook login cookie AND the "Save Browser" cookie persistent (eventually specifying the path, if not the temp) and load it each time in a JFX Panel WebView?

Comment: See also: [Setting a cookie using JavaFX's WebEngine/WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385233/setting-a-cookie-using-javafxs-webengine-webview)

Comment: And also see: [WebView cookie thread on Oracle Forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2326092), which references: [RT-15676: b38: WebView inside applet can't login to certain sites](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15676)

Comment: I was aware of these resources but I was in need of something specific for Facebook login. I edited the question, hoping this helps.

Comment: OK, I removed the duplicate link to: [WebEngine “keep me logged in” functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723308/webengine-keep-me-logged-in-functionality) as the question is now more specific.