# android-spring resttemplate manage cookies

Tags: android, spring, cookies, setcookie

I am using Spring for Android in a project and I need to manage the cookie store/manager. I am able to add cookies to any request by using an implementation of `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`, but I would like to remove some of these when sending a request.

To be more specific, the problem I am facing is that, for Froyo, the implementation specific in `Spring` (with `DefaultHttpClient`) adds automatically to headers the cookies from `CookieStore` - that even if I am setting explicitly the headers. But I would like to manage these cookies myself (either remove some of them, or update their values). While for Gingerbread above (`Spring` implementation is done with `HttpURLConnection`) the cookies are added only if I am doing it myself - however I am not that sure as I don't see Spring setting any `CookieHandler`, but the bottom line is that I don't see them when performing a request or I can see them updated. So the issue is more specific to Froyo.

The work-around is to reset the connection factory; something like:

```
protected void resetCookieStoreForTemplate(RestTemplate template) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        template.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    }
}
```

Underneath, that seems to recreate the DefaultHttpClient and will use a new `CookieStore`. But that seems to me a bit ugly.

To wrap up, my question would be: does [`Spring for Android`](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) provide some method to expose some API for Cookie management? Just the way [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) exposes some abstractions for connectivity, connection factory, message converters and so on, I would be very happy to have some abstraction for cookie management.

Comment: Bounty's gone :( ... Will post this question on `Spring` community and will link that to this question. Thanks all anyway

Answer (score 2):

I've not used Spring myself but from what I've read about it, it follows the official advice and switches HTTP clients based on API version (which is quite clever, if seriously over-engineered for my liking). When using `HTTPUrlConnection`, as you mentioned, Spring probably doesn't change the `CookieHandler`. You should be seeing in-memory cookie handling, so everything should work for requests in the same app run but the cookies would be wiped when you close the app. Can you confirm this is what you're seeing?

If so, all you have to do is create a new `CookieManager` instance, passing it a custom `CookieStore` and `null` for the `CookiePolicy` to use the default.

It's unfortunate that a persistent store isn't built-in but it's not particularly difficult to write one either.

Edit: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349266/how-do-i-persist-cookies-when-using-httpurlconnection) for a CookieStore that uses `SharedPreferences` (haven't tested it myself).

Comment: As mentioned, the issue I am facing is specific for Froyo (http engine is implemented with Apache `DefaultHttpClient`), as I don't see any access to `CookieStore`. The elegant solution in Gingerbread  above (to set a persistent `CookieStore` through `CookieHandler`) works just fine, but I don't have such access to its Apache `CookieStore` implementation. I was hoping to have some API to abstract the access to `CookieStore` ... To be honest, I believe this question should rather be posted on Spring community as it seems to me a feature request.

Comment: Oops, sorry, from your description it sounds like Gingerbread and above are the problem. In that case, yes, it does sound like a feature request and the spring community is the best place for you.

Comment: `from your description it sounds like Gingerbread and above are the problem` ... hmmmm. I've edited a bit the question by adding this: `But I would like to manage these cookies myself (either remove some of them, or update their values).` Hope is more clear. Thanks for flagging that observation!

Comment: I'm using [this post](http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2012/11/how-to-use-ssl-and-session-cookies-with-spring-for-android/) to work with cookies maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` class is a good approach when you need to pass common headers for all requests such as setting up content type, authorization etc. As far as I understood you want to pass some cookie values for specific request.
You could also achieve this via `HttpEntity` and `HttpHeaders` class.

```
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "name=" + value);
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
    ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(
      "http://server/service?...",
      HttpMethod.GET,
      requestEntity,
      Response.class);
```

Spring rest template does not provide any off the self solution for managing cookies. The class `CookieHandler` is provided by Apache not part of spring. Rest template is just a basic solution for managing request response with compare to spring core.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am afraid this is not helping as my question is: `does Spring for Android provide some method to expose some API for Cookie management?` I am already passing a custom `Cookie` as you mentioned (mentioned in 2-nd phrase), but I need to manage the whole cookie store. I can do that in API level 9 above by setting a persistent `CookieStore` in `CookieHandler.setDefault(...)`, but for Froyo I don't see such central cookie repo available to be automatically linked with `DefaultHttpClient`.

Comment: `As far as I understood you want to pass some cookie values for specific request.` I want to remove or to edit these cookies. That works for Gingerbread above, but it doesn't work for Froyo, because it seems to me that `DefaultHttpClient` uses what it has in `CookieStore` ignoring matching headers passed through `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. Off-topic: `CookieHandler` doesn't seem to be provided by Apache as its package name is `java.net`. So my problem is that I don't see any API to access the cookie store. I was hoping to see some abstractions there.

Comment: As said in comment to @Delyan: `To be honest, I believe this question should rather be posted on Spring community as it seems to me a feature request.`