# Retrofit and persistent cookie store

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit

What is the most simple way to implement persistent cookie store on retrofit? Now I am using this:

```
    cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

but I need cookies to be saved and restored any other time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to build your own [CookieStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieStore.html) implementation.  The implementation would be up to you.  You could choose to persistent the data into SharedPreference, flat file, JSON, XML ...

It would look something like so.

```
public class MyCookieStore implements CookieStore {
    // Implementation goes here
}
```

Then you can simply use it like so

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(new MyCookieStore(), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Here's an SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349266/how-do-i-persist-cookies-when-using-httpurlconnection?answertab=votes#tab-top) which attempted to created its own SharedPreference implementation.  It might help you get started.

Comment: Doesnt retrofit use the default cookie manager from Java.net?