# How to share session from a subdomain to another subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.2, session-cookies

I have a login form that points to secure.example.com, it initializes the session and then redirects to www.example.com

When redirected, the session is not created. Going back to secure.example.com then the session is created. Is this a limitation of how cookies work as I think?

Of course I have added the domain: :all in session_store, with the same result.

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My configuration was fine, as I configured `domain: :all`, and that's all what it's needed.

The problem in my case was that I had to define the `domain: :all` in all my cookies, like this:

```
cookies[:new_cookie] = { :value => "value", domain: :all }
```

And when deleting them:

```
cookies.delete :new_cookie, domain: :all
```

After this change, everything works as expected.

Comment: I've been looking for "domain: :all" solution for a long time. This works great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be OK as long as you own example.com and define your cookie domain correctly.  There's a really good answer to how cookies work (or, as the author says, how browsers actually implement them) here: [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)

In rails, just pass the proper value for `:domain` when setting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same session_key in both apps. In appA environment.rb change the session_key, like this

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ...  
   config.action_controller.session = {
   :session_key => '_portal_session',
   :secret      => '72bf006c18d459acf51836d2aea01e0afd0388f860fe4b07a9a57dedd25c631749ba9b65083a85af38bd539cc810e81f559e76d6426c5e77b6064f42e14f7415'
   }
   ...
   end
```

Do the same in AppB. (remember to use the very same secret)

Now you have shared sessions. Let's say you use restfull_authentication, wich sets a session variable called user_id. When you authenticate in appA it sets the user_id in the session. Now, in appB you just have to verify if user_id exists in the session.

This is the overall schema, you can elaborate more using this idea.