# Setting domain cookie from subdomain

Tags: http, cookies

Under domain cookie in question I mean cookie with domain like `.domain.com`.
I can read this cookie from any subdomain, but can I sett this cookie with new value from domain `example.domain.com`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do browser cookie domains work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)