# Csrf token isn't being created in subdomain

Tags: yii, csrf, csrf-protection

I activated csrf protection on my project which runs on Yii framework.
Csrf token is being created when base domain runs like "www.example.com".
But it isn't being created when the subdomain runs like "admin.example.com".

The configuration:

```
'components'=>array(
        'request' => array(
            'class' => 'application.components.HttpRequest',
                    'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
            ),
             ...
```

What is the problem in my code or is it about the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the [CSRF cookie params](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#csrfCookie-detail) in the `request` component in your `main.php` configuration:

```
'components' => array(
    'request' => array(
        'csrfCookie' => array(
            'domain' => '.example.com',
        ),
     ),
 ),
```

Check out the other [cookie options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpCookie). You may also have to tweak the cookie path. This may also be helpful:

[How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)