# Drupal migration one folder to another

Tags: php, drupal

previously my setting page in which all page working  that were

```
$base_url = 'mysiteurl'
$cookie_domain = '.mysite'
```

and i have changed this to

```
 $base_url = 'mysiteurl/m2'
    $cookie_domain = '.mysite/m2'
```

I want to move a Drupal site from one folder to another, 
    I have moved all files into new location and set base path in setting.php 
    to its new location but it is not working only home page of
    site is running in new folder but  the links to inside pages are unlikely to work.
    Click on any links and I am getting "Not Found" errors. 
    what should I do to shortout this.
    my home page is working  cool rest pages are not working. 
    always through page not found error

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The new value of the `$base_url` is correct. However, the new domain of the cookie seems to be wrong. I suggest you to go through [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/1312737)

And regarding the 404 error for the internal pages, you might want to clear all the caches. If you can do that via UI, you can do it by truncating the tables prefixed by `cache_`. This will cause the menus to be rebuilt on the next page load, and the site should work fine.

Comment: thank u Ajit for suggesting me.i have solved this issue i only commented the $cookie_domain it is working fine for me