# How To Authenticate Across Subdomains

Tags: authentication, go, cross-domain

I'm working on a web application which actually consists of two applications under the hood. One application is called `account` and handles all things related to user accounts such authentication, registration and management of the account. I also have an application we'll just call `web`.

The thing is that `account` listens on https://account.domain.com using SSL/TLS, and web listens on http://www.domain.com.

What options do I have for having people log in and authenticate `account.domain.com` and then redirecting them to `www.domain.com` where they're actually then logged in. As far as I know, you can't set up a cookie on `account.domain.com` and then have it work on `domain.com` as that would be a security risk.

Some background details about my applications:

1. Written in the Go programming language.
2. Makes use of the Gorilla Toolkit for most of the HTTP/HTTPS interfacing, URL routing and handling POST/GET parameters.
3. Both applications live on the same virtual server.

What I'm looking for is a secure way to authenticate and manage a session across all subdomains of and the actual domain `domain.com`.  I'm not particularly well versed in this subject, so aside from setting cookies, I don't know much.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot set a domain cookie with domain=domain.com from the domain account.domain.com? As long as the browser accepts domain.com as an ETLD+1 (see publicsuffix.org) it will work.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what public suffix is or how it works, but on digging into it doesn't sound like this is supported by all major browsers. I need something that works for at least the latest versions of IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: This may not answer your broader session management question, but you should be able to set a cookie on .domain.com from anything.domain.com--details about the public suffix list won't come up here. Just make sure [Cookie.Domain](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie) is .domain.com, not www.domain.com. (This also seems like a browser/HTTP/JavaScript question more than a Go question.)

Comment: @Jesse: All major browsers determine the ETLD+1 in some way or the other. Publicsuffix.org is *the* reference here and is safe to use. All this has nothing to do with browsers but with what your "domain.com" really is.

Comment: The real problem here is that using a cookie across both domains (which means `Secure: false`) is that an attacker—someone sitting in a café or taking advantage of an XSS exploit—can easily modify (MITM; café) or read (XSS, if `HttpOnly: True`) the cookie contents. So be absolutely sure you're not storing anything critical or used solely to identify privileges. Better still would be to just put `www.domain.com` behind TLS/SSL too.

Comment: @elithrar The cookie merely stores a session ID. The server actually keeps a token and a hash of the IP address + agent to identify the user. Any further advice I could use to identify the user?

Comment: What happens if someone reads the session ID? Or a user on a mobile device goes through a tunnel?

Comment: The session ID, is, like I said, mapped to a token that is sent with each request to the browser (and has to be returned), and is also mapped to a hash of the user agent + ip address. This is obviously not completely fail safe, but it doesn't necessarily have to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with gorilla but something like should work:

```
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("something-very-secret"))

func init() {
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Domain:   "domain.com", //this
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
}
```

Basically you just have to set the cookie's domain to `.domain.com` (with the prefix `.`), there's a more detailed explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/145587

//edit

According to @Volker, the dot isn't needed (see comments).

Comment: There is no need to start the domain with a dot: "domain=domain.com" works just as well as "domain=.domain.com" on all browsers. See RFC 6265 which is widely adopted.