# How to set default domain on HttpCookie in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Hi I need to setup a super cookie for my site.
the issue is that my site is on 2 domain, one domain for the intranet and one for the web.
example:
mySite.com
mySite.IntraNetDMZ.com

So i can't simply set the domain on the web.config httpCookies node, I believe I need to set it in code. I taught of putting it on the master page for the site on load to set the domain name based on the caller's url. To do so i need to know how to override the value that i have in the web.config. I don't want to refactor the entire code and the login process to manually set the value, so i want to chagne my site global setting.

Anyone has an idea on how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start with these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sam. I read through the specification but the examples are reflecting what I was seeing so far. I can only have one top domain for all of my sites which is not the case.I will keep on looking but so far my solution seems to be adding an encrypted queryString value.