# Share cookie across domain and subdomain

Tags: php, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I've two application running on 2 different servers (also different IP).

The first application (Ruby) is running on test.domain.com.
The second application (PHP) is running on domain.com.

Is it possible to set a cookie on the first application which is readable/accessible by the second application. For the sake of clarity the two applications are running on different servers.

Comment: You have to set a cookie to have the domain set to domain.com so that it should be accessible to both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work