# SignalR Core, error: The 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value 'u1mOHwcpjPm7txGcxCm1jVmOgjo=' is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to implement SignalR Core in a `.Net core 2.0` Web app, and implement client side in a `Xamarin.Android` application.
I created a fresh .Net core 2.0 Web app solution and imported `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` and setup the Startup.cs file like in this sample

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/blob/master/ChatSample/ChatSample/Startup.cs

My code:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseFileServer();

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat");
        });
    }
}
```

This project is deployed to Amazon Elastic Bean Stalk.

On the client side, I have imported `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` and I initialize a connection like in this sample

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/blob/master/XamarinAndroidChatClient/XamarinAndroidChatClient/MainActivity.cs

My code:

```
    public async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://*******.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/chat")
                .Build();
        try
        {
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

But `.StartAsync()` throws this exception:

> {System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value 'LNqQiPhES/zOwW10TMji4AVvvoA=' is invalid.
>     at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ValidateAndTrackHeader (System.String targetHeaderName, System.String targetHeaderValue, System.String foundHeaderName, System.String foundHeaderValue, System.Boolean& foundHeader) [0x0002c] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0 `

I found this post which was related to Amazon ELB and setting up websockets

([Elastic Beanstalk stripping Sec-WebSocket-Accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187664/elastic-beanstalk-stripping-sec-websocket-accept-header))

Also found this post with same problem

(https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=613220)

As in this post, things are working fine if I choose "LongPolling" as transport

```
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://*******.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/chat")
                .WithTransport(TransportType.LongPolling)
                .Build();
```

This guy was suggested to switch LoadBalancer listeners from HTTP to TCP, I tried this, but issue is still remaining
Also I read a suggestion to install websockets in ISS on AWS Management Console, but I can't find this option anywhere?

Any kind of help or suggestions are appreciated

Comment: No ideas, no help, no suggestions? Really?

Comment: Have similar issue. let's keep waiting for our hero.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to log onto the Elastic BeanStalk server and enable the Websocket Protocol on in the server roles in Server Manager, this fixed it for me.