# I cant share cookie to my sub domain when my parent domain contain www prefix , with out www i can

Tags: .net, cookies

my Parent domain: aswajith.com 
My sub domain : Cookie.aswajith.com

I can successfully share cookie to my SubDomain using the below code:

```
      HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
      hc.Domain = ".aswajith.com";
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(hc);
      Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserInfo"].Value;
```

But i cant share when i change my parent domain to "www.aswajith.com" instead of aswajith.com .

What is the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

> .aswajith.com

This makes the cookie available to all subdomains of `asawjith.com` : `www.asawjith.com`, `cookie.asawjith.com`, ...

Now if you set it to `.www.aswajith.com` it wont be visible to other subdomains of `aswajith.com` nor the parent domain. This is by design but it can be availble to subdomains of `www.aswajith.com`.

For more information about domain in cookies :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109
- [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)