# Why can foo.example.com set cookies for example.com?

Tags: http, cookies

From both the documentation and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work), I already know that the fact is `foo.example.com` can set cookies for `example.com` by sending response with `Domain = example.com` in the `Set-Cookie` header. But why is this allowed?

For example, the fact is, a server (say, `foo.example.com`) cannot set cookies for its siblings (say, `bar.example.com`) or the domain names lower than it (also known as "its child", say, `ide.foo.example.com`), but it can set cookies for the domain names higher than it (also known as "its parents", in this case `example.com`.

Let me make the statement of the question even more clear by putting it into the real world. Just like apps on Google App Engine, `foo.appspot.com` obviously cannot set cookies for `bar.appspot.com` because they are two different apps, and they shouldn't affect each other's behavior. But why is it allowed for `foo.appspot.com` to set cookies for `appspot.com` by sending `Domain = appspot.com` in its response header? By doing this the `foo.appspot.com` app can actually affect other apps' behavior on Google App Engine, since the browser will send this cookie when visiting `bar.appspot.com`, the domain name of which is a child of `appspot.com`.

I learned all these things about cookies from the Web Development course on Udacity. But I'm really confused with this question. Can anybody help explain this? Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is horribly outdated. Too bad people googling "cookie domain" will find it first.

I should write a better one; but for now, to quickly answer your question - it is about "public suffix" domain.

Can server "example.com" set a cookie for "com"? Nope, because "com" is a public suffix.

Can "foo.co.uk" set a cookie for "co.uk"? Nope, because "co.uk" is a public suffix.

It happens that "appspot.com" is also a public suffix; so "foo.appspot.com" cannot set a cookie with domain="appspot.com". (It can, but browsers will reject it)

Unfortunately, there's no algorithm to determine which is a public suffix. The list of all public suffix is maintained manually at https://publicsuffix.org/