# Setting cookie for different domain from javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set cookie to domain same as src of js file.

Scenario:
In **www.xyz.com** html, I have included js file from qwe.com as below

```js
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://qwe.com/b.js"></script>
```

From this b.js, i want to create cookie with domain set to .qwe.com. I am setting cookie with following function

```js
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
      var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+";domain=.qwe.com"+"; path=/;";
  }
```

With above code I am unable to set cookie. 
Example: www.flipkart.com-> Check cookies in resources tab of developer console-> .scorecardresearch.com and .doubleclick.net are able to set cookie

I want to do same. Can someone please share solution for this? Real working solution. I have tried multiple solutions by doing Google search. It didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Client side JavaScript can set cookies only for the domain the webpage is hosted on.

The examples you cite use [HTTP headers to set cookies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), not JavaScript.

Comment: Hey Quentin, thanks for reference. I am a beginner at very early stage. Can you please explain a bit?  How to accomplish it using HTTP headers to set cookies? 
I checked another answer on HTTP headers [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work). It seems it can not be accomplished with it.

Please help in clarification.

Comment: How you set HTTP headers depends on the server side language you use on the server. That link is about setting headers for a different domain, you aren't trying to do that: Script comes from example.com, cookies set for example.com.