# function of cookies only return cookies from one domain in clojure webdriver

Tags: selenium, cookies, clojure, webdriver

I login into a website using clj-webdriver of firefox, when using cookie manager add-on in firefox, it shows there are several domain such as

```
ac.example.com
example.com
www.example.com
```

Then use the function of cookies to check all the cookies,

https://crossclj.info/fun/clj-webdriver.taxi/cookies.html

but it only shows cookie from `example.com`, other cookies are missing from the result value. I need to have all these cookies so that I want to copy these cookie to use inside clj-http, but since it missing some cookie, so when use clj-http it still need me to login in. What I am wanting to do is login using webdirver, export the cookies into clj-http, and then use clj-http to get data from webside with high performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t say which domain you’re on explicitly, but it looks like `example.com`. I think what you’re seeing is browser cookie security not letting you reach across domains. These links have more infomation on Same Origin Policy.

- [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy