# Why isn't this cookie valid?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

This is the cookie:

```
{'secure': False, 'domain': '.dashnet.org', 'httpOnly': True, 'path': '/', 'name': '__cfduid', 'expiry': None, 'value': 'd0c8a701ccb379dc7ac094575c111d6051487290749'}
```

When trying to add it to Firefox using the Selenium module for Python, i got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    browser.add_cookie(cookies[0])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 671, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: InvalidCookieDomainError is not defined
```

So, what is the problem with this cookie?

Comment: That looks like a bug in the selenium code because `InvalidCookieDomainError` is not defined but I am not familiar enough to be sure. However, that error should still give you a clue of where to look. Make sure the domain is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676300/2158288:

"The cookie domain should not have a leading dot, as in .foo.com - simply use foo.com"

Maybe that's the problem.