# Why isn't the cookie set for the request? but it is saved on the cookie of the browser

Tags: cookies, next.js, fastify

I'm using Fastify-Next.js Stack.
Fastify port: 5000, Frontend port: 3000

On the browser, cookie storage has a cookie named token.
But for the requests, the cookie isn't set.
I guess for the requests to 3000 port(frontend), the cookie is set.
But for the Backend server, it isn't the same.

[image]

---

[image]

I'm confirming the request by using a token.
On the Fastify server, I have to get a cookie.
But I can't get it. Because the cookie is not set for the request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing Cookie between different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378033/sharing-cookie-between-different-ports)