# Login a website automatically with nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, request, passport.js

I am making a website (named webA) using nodejs. I want to be able to automatically log in another website (name webB) each time I access webA.

I searched at Google and realized that I need to use cookies to this? My code is now like below:

```
var cookie = require('cookie');
var escapeHtml = require('escape-html');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

function onRequest(req, res) {

  var cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || ''); 
    cookies.name = 'user_abcd';
    cookies.password = '1234';

    //post a request to webB ???
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

If I understand correctly, I guess I will need to 'construct' a request using the cookies I made, then send a post request to webB. Am I on the right track? Any codes will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This should done through proper SSO implementation. Spoofing auth cookies are not recommended. Moreover WebB needs to have proper `CORS` configuration to allow this.

Comment: @nilobarp thanks for quick reply. As a beginner in web scraping, I am just seeking for the most basic method to achieve automatically login function, which can significantly help me to understand the process, after which I can try to do it in more professional way.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be passed in the `headers` of a `http request` like so

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'example.de',
    path: '/pathexample',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
        'Cookie': '<cookie string>',
        'Accept': '/',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
};
```

Then use this option object in

```
http.request(options, function (resp) { ... });
```

Also check [HTTP CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) & [Cookie Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Do I simply replace '<cookie string>' with my variable 'cookies' in this case to make it work?

Comment: Yes that’s right. You may also need to base64 encode the string if WebB expects it that way.