# Laravel memcached - same session across domains

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I have seen topics about this but all were about using memcached / database about it and my approach is similar.

Here is what I have:

- I have 2 domains lets say: dev.com and dev.eu
- I want to persist the session + [shopping cart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) when I go between those 2 domains. If I add something to cart in dev.com I want to see it in dev.eu too.
- I am using Laravel 5.6 and I am using memcached for sessions.
- Just to be clear both domains are pointed to the same server.

Thanks for any ideas

Here are my config files

## session.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'memcached',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
    | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
    | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
    |
    */

    'store' => 'memcached',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => "app",

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

## cache.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
    | using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
    | not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
    |
    | Supported: "apc", "array", "database", "file", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'default' => "memcached",

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Stores
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
    | well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
    | same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
    |
    */

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => null,
            'sasl' => [],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => 11211,
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Key Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
    | be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
    | value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => "app_cache"

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. Laravel's session management identifies the client based on a cookie sent to that client. Such cookies cannot be shared between different domains of type dev.com and dev.eu, only between seperate subdomains. For a detailed example of what can be done with cookies and domain restrictions see for example the answers to [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)

Comment: What about some workaround with just shopping cart? That shopping cart can be set up to use database as storing option. Would that be possible?

Comment: the core of the issue, for both session and shopping cart data, is that you will need some way to identify which client is which. Since cookies are out (barring some workarounds that you really shouldn't want anyway), if you really want this you could have users login or something similar and use that as an identifying measure. But if you really want to serve identical content for both domains, why not choose 1 of them and have the other only act as a redirect?

Comment: Cos it is geotargetted for countries .sk .cz .it .es some of those have separate databases etc. I might go for subdomains then