# Cookies domain prepended with www.*

Tags: php, nginx, cookies

I have a nginx setup with php for a client of mine. When I set a cookie I notice that it looks something like this:

```
.www.stackoverflow.com
```

But when I compare this to other websites, they set cookies with domain like this:

```
.stackoverflow.com
```

This means that a subdomain cannot share the cookie unless its something like subdomains.www.stackoverflow.com.

Do you know why they would want to keep theWhere is this  .www.? I assume this is set based on the server_name in the nginx config too? Could I simply remove the "www"?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is cookies with a domain prefix are more secure due to a process known as domain matching. Refer to this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work) for more information.