# Setting Cookies at TLD (cross domain tracking)

Tags: session, cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies, google-tag-manager

If you are a owner of a TLD (so you are the owner of for example *.global domain), and you want to set crossdomain tracking for multiple domains (so my.global, your.global, our.global) . What would be the best way of doing it? We want to keep the session and the user as one while he is navigating all those domains.

What to tell the dev team in the topic of cookies? I believe it is possible to set the cookies at the .global level (instead of my.global, your.global and so on)?

*A side question, how to configure GTM for that?

Comment: If you can afford to own a TLD you can afford to hire someone to design that solution for you :) Since cookies can't be tracked at TLD (for obvious security reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work), what you're after is an `end-to-end architecture that addresses web development, analytics, and legal aspects of the matter`. I believe you will find it hard to get this from SO which is best used to answer 1 specific `technical` problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When you will configure Cross-Domain Tracking in GTM, you should set the value 'auto' for the field 'cookieDomain'. In this case cookie will be set on top level domain.

[image]