# Laravel session ID changes on each request

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Every time I reload the page, I get a new value out of `session()->getId()`.

Some have suggested adding the `laravel_session` to the unencrypted cookie exception, but this does not fix it and is not a viable option anyway.

The issue persists no matter which session storage method I use. File, redis, etc all have the same problem.

This is happening on a fresh install of Laravel 7.

Contents of .env:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=1440
SESSION_DOMAIN=example.test
```

What's causing this?

Comment: CHECK inside Kernel.php and make sure you dont have duplicate classes like StartSession, AuthenticateSession, Specially inside middleware groups array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means:

1. Session driver is not starting up properly
2. Client you're using to connect to laravel app server does not accept cookies
3. Cookies are set up for wrong domain and/or path.

For case 1 make sure `StartSession` middleware exists in `app/Kernel.php` at `$middlewareGroups` -> `web`

For case 3 check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/8555937). In case your app relies on a single domain/path, I recommend you to remove `SESSION_DOMAIN`.

---

Finally, manually remove all sessions from your session driver, then run `php artisan config:cache` and try again.

Comment: The issue was that I didn't put my middleware that reads the session in the `web` section but instead put it in the general middleware array where `StartSession` middleware was not defined.