# How to determine the third-party domain of another?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, privacy-policy

Is `bbb.xxx.com` the third-party domain of `aaa.xxx.com`?
Or
Is `bbb.xxx.com` the third-party domain of `xxx.com`?

According to MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#third-party_cookies

> A cookie is associated with a domain. If this domain is the same as the domain of the page you are on, the cookie is called a first-party cookie. If the domain is different, it is a third-party cookie.

So what does `different` mean?I'm confused with it.

## I have had a Test

### Environment Info

Browser: Chrome 89.0.4389.114
[image]

### test steps

I hava a `https://aaa.xxx.com` website. And inside it there is an iframe whose src is `https://bbb.xxx.com`.
The result shows `https://bbb.xxx.com`'s cookies can be passed in it's request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)

Comment: i dont thing so. The problem is case of iframe

Answer (score 0):

Neither is the true.

`Third-party cookies, are cookies that are stored under a different domain than you are currently visiting.`

So if the outerpage is `aaa.com` and that page contains an iframe element that references `bbb.com`, then `bbb.com` is the 'third-party' and will be subject to all of the third-party cookie and storage restrictions.

The key is understanding the nesting of the frames, and any frame from an origin that doesn't match the url bar, is 'third-party'.