# AJAX not sending my cookie to NODE JS SERVER

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I have an API in NodeJs where I need to validate a token to let a user pass that middleware and retrieve `storeId`.
I have a cookie with `ts` key in my localhost :
[cookie ts in application dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1wsO.png)

And I have my AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: 'http://www.localhost:8090/product',
    data: product,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    success: result => {
        console.log(result)
        $('#FormLoading').remove()
    }
})
```

And for some reason it still doesn't send the token but
in other pages like homepage dashboard it works.
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk5yM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ts` key is for `localhost` domain and you are calling `http://www.localhost:8090/product`. Normally if the domain of your cookies are like the domain of the API URL, the `cookie` key and its **value** will be inserted in the **header** request automatically as a string series. But here the domain of your cookie is `localhost` and domain of the API is `www.localhost`. So **AJAX** ignores the cookie.You should set the cookie domain with wildcard, when generating cookie in **node js** server response to login request, or change the base URL of the API to `localhost`. By the way this may help [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)